# Auto Resizing Nattable for single row in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

In application have a view which contains Nattable.

In that table, When I use the filter to search for a String and there is just only one row left, if you then change the column width all columns change width.

I read it in one of the forum as because that row is selected so all column will be resized.

Please let me know how can i resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First question, if you read on the NatTable forum about this topic, why do you then raise a question on Stackoverflow instead of writing to the forum?

Second question, why is the row selected? I am not aware of any feature that would select a row on filtering.

I think it is a common behavior that you resize all columns that are selected, and if you only have one row and that row is selected, it means all columns are fully selected. So IMHO it is the correct behavior. The only way to change this is to override SelectionLayer#handleColumnResizeCommand to disable the multi column resize feature. There is currently no option to modify that behavior.

You can also open an enhancement ticket to get such an option included in NatTable and provide a patch.

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer of Dirk not really valid.

I think the selection of body-rows/cells has nothing to do with the selection of the header region. The selection of all columns (let's say by selecting the columns with their headers-rectangles) is something completly different as selecting a data-row.

However, I found a quick fix which turns off all the multi-hide, -resize and -clear functionality very easily. This may be a little bit dirty, but it helped me for the first:

```
class MySelectionLayer extends SelectionLayer {
    public MySelectionLayer(IUniqueIndexLayer underlyingLayer) {
        super(underlyingLayer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isColumnPositionFullySelected(int columnPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer is valid for NatTable. Whether you think it is correct as a design in general or not. If you think it is wrong in NatTable, feel free to create a bug ticket for this. Your hack also disables rendering columns differently when they are fully selected and probably even more.